# Why can't I send ZIP files in Apple Mail from an iCloud account?

Tags: icloud, mail.app

When I try to send a zip file to a gmail user from Apple Mail with my iCloud address, I get the following error. My zip file is 5 MB but contains a lot of files inside the archive (that's why I zipped it so I wouldn't be sending a hundred separate files). Basically, Apple Mail treats the zip archive like it is unzipped or something like that. Does anybody know a workaround?

[image]

Comment: I’m not getting a size violation error but a number of files error.

Comment: @Jackson Please read the duplicate before dismissing it. The duplicate contains an answer for your exact question.

Comment: I see I guess it is similar but Apple changed the server's error message.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I tarred my zip archive. So I used the tar command in the terminal (tar -cf output.tar input.zip) and then emailed the tarred zip file. I guess this prevents Apple from trying to count how many files are in the zip archive.